# Find the unique lifting for $f:S^1 \to S^1$ given by $f(z)=z^2$, where $z=x+iy, x^2+y^2=1$

Tags: general-topology, universal-property

Let $f:S^1 \to S^1$ be given by $f(z)=z^2$, where $z=x+iy, x^2+y^2=1$. Then find the unique lift $\bar f: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ with the properties that 
(i) $\bar f(1)=0$ and
(ii) $E \circ \bar f=f$, where $E:\mathbb{R} \to S^1$ is the map $E(t)=e^{2\pi it}=cos(2\pi t)+isin(2\pi t)$.

Please help, I couldn't find the lifting $\bar f$. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I Just been told the original statement is a false statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall De Moivre's formula that says that $(cos(\theta)+isin(\theta))^n=cos(n\theta)+isin(n\theta)$. So now it becomes clear that since elements of $S^1$ are only dependent on their arguments, the map $\bar{f}$ simply needs to send an element of $S^1$ to twice its argument which is an element of $\mathbb{R}$, (with some refinement with the way you have set up the map $E$, personally I would have described $E$ simply to be $t \mapsto e^{it}$). I am concerned that the map $\bar{f}$ will be discontinuous but this is the only option if you wish for $E \circ \bar{f}=f$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, I think you meant $\bar f(z)=[Arg(z)]^2/2\pi$? and may I ask how do I show uniqueness?

Comment: You have misunderstood what is happening with the arguments. $f$ can be rewritten as $e^{i\theta} \mapsto e^{i2\theta}$ and therefore $\bar{f}$ has to be $e^{i\theta} \mapsto \frac{2\theta}{\pi}$ in your set up. If you think about where the elements are being sent here then uniqueness is clear.